# XmlDocument Helper methods

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm having to use .NET 2.0 so can't use any of the nice XDocument stuff.

I'm wondering if anyone has seen any helper/utility methods that still use XmlDocument but make xml creation a bit less tedious?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [XmlHandler class in Pluto](http://trac.assembla.com/plugintoolkit/browser/trunk/Pluto.Configuration/Implementation/XmlHandler.cs).

It uses XmlDocument internally, but allows very simple reading and writing of values, including handling arrays, classes, etc, with reading and writing to specific locations via XPath queries.